# Alarm Clock Plus says wrong temperature; wrong by 20 or more degrees

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-2, alarm, news-and-weather

I enabled the "Say time before alarm" and "say weather before alarm" features on Alarm Clock Plus, but when alarm activates the wrong temperature is being said. Not by a few degrees, but by 20 or more. For example, the temperature is 30 C, and I hear "It is 2 C"! I did not have this problem with the free version.

I have Galaxy S2 and it seems that the temperature is read from Samsung's built in "News and Weather" app. I tried changing my location in "News and Weather" thinking that the data for my location may be corrupted, but it did not fix the issue. No matter which location I choose, it says the wrong temperature.

How can I fix this so that the correct temperature will be used? I'd really hate to rate this alarm app badly as it's really good except for this irritating bug.

Comment: Is it always off in the same direction -- i.e. always says a lower temperature? Could it have to do with units, e.g. using °F instead of °C, or even °R?

Comment: @Izzy unfortunately the issue is not with the Farads and Celsius

Comment: Maybe it's getting wrong data from its provider. I have two devices with AlarmDroid running, and noticed they give different temperatures for the same location even -- though not that far different.